# Drawing complex shapes in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad

I have two parallel lines intersecting a circle.  Is there a command that will break the drawing up into separate pieces (2) at the intersection points? I want to send up with what's in (3).

[image]

Comment: I would look into perhaps parsing your shape with a ulp, or better yet try to see if anyone on the intertubes has written a similar ulp already. The Eagle forums are great for stuff like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike AutoCAD or SolidWorks, there is no command in Eagle, which would break or trim lines at intersections.

Your shape isn't very complex.  There are several options.

- Find/calculate the coordinates of the intersection points.  Then draw 2 separate arcs and 2 separate lines.
- Draw a rectangle.  Then change the `Curve` property of the sides, which will make them into arcs.

Comment: Did you mean to draw an actual Rectangle, or draw 4 lines? I got what you suggested to work with the lines, but not with the rectangle.

Comment: I meant drawing 4 lines.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Not really the easiest way to get the job done, but it works.